# Create t2 instance and connect via Wokrbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I've created an t2 RDS instance inside a VPC. The instance is set to `Publicly avaiable: No`. I wasn't able to connect to the instance using MySQL Workbench. Is there an option to connect to the instance in that state?

I also tried to create with `Publicly available: Yes`, but I get the following error upon creation:

> Cannot create a publicly accessible DBInstance because customer VPC does not support DNS resolution and/or hostnames.

How can I solve this? -- I want to be able to create a database in t2 and connect to a t2 RDS instance from Workbench.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> customer VPC does not support DNS resolution and/or hostnames.

A quick search for the error message uncovers what it means: your VPC (Amazon Virtual Private Cloud) is not configured to support DNS resolution and/or hostnames, both of which are required to make an RDS instance inside VPC publicly accessible.

The solution appears to be to configure the VPC with these capabilities enabled, after, of course, considering why they might have been disabled to begin with.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=153914

Answer (score 1):

To enable DNS resolution and DNS hostnames for your VPC, open the **VPC Management Console** > **Your VPCs**. Click on your VPC and then click on **Actions** and then enable both **Edit DNS Resolution** & **Edit DNS Hostnames**.[image]